# Python: VSCode does not show docstring for inherited exceptions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

```
class CustomNamedException(Exception):
    """Example docstring here."""

    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self._name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return("Error message.")
```

My exception above does not show the docstring when I use the class in VSCode, what appears in the info box is instead `Common base class for all exceptions`.

Screenshot:

[image]

Seems redundant to include the base class docstring instead of the actual exception when I call it. I want `Example docstring here.` to display instead. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**
The docstring for `__init__()` instead actually appears if I give it one:

[image]

Is this basically the intended behaviour? Are docstrings ignored when you inherit from the BaseException class unless you put it in `__init__()`?

Comment: Wild guess: In the context, you are essentially calling the `__init__()` method and therefore its docstring is shown. As an annotation or a variable, the reference is understood as referring to the class and therefore the class's docstring [is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YabJ.png).

Comment: @InSync This is correct, just tried it. That solves my question, though that's weird to me, since other classes without an inherited exception don't have this behaviour with docstrings. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for whether this is intentional or not, but here's what the behaviour seems to be:

```
class BaseClass:
    """BaseClass docstring"""
    def __init__():
        """BaseClass __init__ docstring"""
        pass
class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    """DerivedClass docstring"""
    def __init__():
        """DerivedClass __init__ docstring""" # <-
        pass
DerivedClass() # DerivedClass __init__ docstring
```

```
class BaseClass:
    """BaseClass docstring"""
    def __init__():
        """BaseClass __init__ docstring""" # <-
        pass
class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    """DerivedClass docstring"""
    def __init__():
        # """DerivedClass __init__ docstring""" # commented out
        pass
DerivedClass() # BaseClass __init__ docstring
```

```
class BaseClass:
    """BaseClass docstring"""
    def __init__():
        # """BaseClass __init__ docstring""" # commented out
        pass
class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    """DerivedClass docstring""" # <-
    def __init__():
        # """DerivedClass __init__ docstring""" # commented out
        pass
DerivedClass() # DerivedClass docstring
```

```
class BaseClass:
    """BaseClass docstring"""
    def __init__():
        # """BaseClass __init__ docstring""" # commented out
        pass
class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    # """DerivedClass docstring""" # commented out
    def __init__():
        # """DerivedClass __init__ docstring""" # commented out
        pass
DerivedClass() # N/A
```

It's not quite that it's not showing the derived class' docstring. It's that it's looking for a docstring on `__init__`, and not finding it, first falls back to the base class' `__init__` docstring if that exists (and in the case of the question post, it did).

I do agree this could be awkward according to taste, and I imagine it could be problematic if the derived class' constructor has a very different signature than the base class, but I don't think this is a necessarily terrible design either / I can kind of empathize with this choice of behaviour.